# Cloud SQL (GCP) postgres - how to show database number of connections configured

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform

I would like to know the number of connections configured for a postgres database (not the max_connections setting for the instance).  By default it is set to -1 (unlimited) but someone has changed that configuration for a particular database.    How can I determine what the current setting is for a specific database on a GCP Cloud SQL Postgres instance?

This command is used to change the connection limit for a postgres db:

alter database yourDBName CONNECTION LIMIT nbr;

What is "nbr" for a particular database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will do it:

select
datname         as  DbName,
datconnlimit    as  DbConnectionLimit
from
pg_database
order by
datname asc;